# TikZ - Game theory tree with continuum of moves (depicted as a gray triangle)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, forest, trees

In extensive form games (game trees), we usually draw a (gray) triangle in the background of the player's branch (strategy) to denote that the player has a continuum of actions available at that node. For example, in the game tree I am sending below I manually draw the triangles for player PM. Player PM has to choose an *x* (that can assume any value from 0 to 1). However, I don't know how to draw the triangles using Ti*k*Z in LaTeX. I am sending what I am looking for:

[image]

Below, I am sending the Ti*k*Z code I wrote to produce my tree (without the triangles, of course):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sgame, tikz} % Game theory packages
\usetikzlibrary{trees,backgrounds,calc,positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,font=\footnotesize]
\tikzset{
% Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}
% Specify spacing for each level of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=8mm,sibling distance=20mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=8mm,sibling distance=20mm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=8mm,sibling distance=20mm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=8mm,sibling distance=20mm]
\tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=2.5]
\tikzstyle directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[arrowstyle]{stealth}}}}]
% The Tree
\node(0)[hollow node,label=above:{$PM$}]{}
child{node(2)[solid node,label=right:{$l_{i}$}]{}
child{node(3)[hollow node,label=left:{$PM$}]{}
    child { node [solid node, label=left:$l_{i}$] {}
      child { 
        node {\emph{x}}
          edge from parent
            node[left, xshift=-3] {$Y$}}
        child { node [solid node, label=right:$l_{i}$] {}
          child { node [solid node,label=right:$l_{i}$] {}
            child { 
              node {\emph{ne}}
                edge from parent
                  node[left, xshift=-3] {$A$}}
            child { 
              node {$\ddots$}
                edge from parent
                  node[right, xshift=3] {$\neg A$}}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {}
              edge from parent
                node[left] {$VNC$}}
          child { 
            node {$\ddots$}
              edge from parent
                node[right] {$\neg VNC$}}
           edge from parent
             node[right] {}
          edge from parent
            node[right, xshift=2] {$N$}}
       edge from parent
         node[right] {$x$}}
edge from parent node[left, xshift=-3]{$A$}}
child{node(4)[label=below:{$SQ$}]{}
edge from parent node[right]{$\neg A$}
}
edge from parent node[right,xshift=3]{$p$}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably add the triangles in the background layer. To this end, I load the library `backgrounds` (and `calc` for coordinate mending).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,font=\footnotesize]
\tikzset{
% Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}
% Specify spacing for each level of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=8mm,sibling distance=20mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=8mm,sibling distance=20mm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=8mm,sibling distance=20mm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=8mm,sibling distance=20mm]
\tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=2.5]
\tikzstyle directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[arrowstyle]{stealth}}}}]
% The Tree
\node(0)[hollow node,label=above:{$PM$}]{}
child{node(2)[solid node,label=right:{$l_{i}$}]{}
child{node[hollow node,label=left:{$PM$}](3){}
    child { node[solid node, label=left:$l_{i}$](5) {}
      child { 
        node{\emph{x}}
          edge from parent
            node[left, xshift=-3] {$Y$}}
        child { node [solid node, label=right:$l_{i}$] {}
          child { node [solid node,label=right:$l_{i}$] {}
            child { 
              node {\emph{ne}}
                edge from parent
                  node[left, xshift=-3] {$A$}}
            child { 
              node {$\ddots$}
                edge from parent
                  node[right, xshift=3] {$\neg A$}}
             edge from parent
               node[right] {}
              edge from parent
                node[left] {$VNC$}}
          child { 
            node {$\ddots$}
              edge from parent
                node[right] {$\neg VNC$}}
           edge from parent
             node[right] {}
          edge from parent
            node[right, xshift=2] {$N$}}
       edge from parent
         node[right] {$x$}}
edge from parent node[left, xshift=-3]{$A$}}
child{node(4)[label=below:{$SQ$}]{}
edge from parent node[right]{$\neg A$}
}
edge from parent node[right,xshift=3]{$p$}
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[fill=gray!40](0.south)--($(2)+(0.6cm,0)$)--($(2)-(0.6cm,0)$)--cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!40](3.south)--($(5)+(0.6cm,0)$)--($(5)-(0.6cm,0)$)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to draw the triangles with no (black) borders?

Comment: @Thiago Sure, just replace `\draw` by `\fill` in the commands inside the scope.

Answer (score 6):

Well, Forest would be easier if you have to draw several. For example, your tree could be specified as follows:

```
\begin{forest}
  dec tree,
  [PM
    [l_i, my label=p, cont
      [PM, my label=A
        [l_i, my label=x, cont
          [x, my label=Y]
          [l_i, my label=N
            [l_i, my label=VNC
              [ne, my label=A]
              [, my label=\lnot A]
            ]
            [, my label=\lnot VNC]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Sq, my label=\lnot A]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

where `my label` sets up the edge labels, `dec tree` enables the overall style, and `cont` sets a triangle for the parent of the current node.

[image: <code>dec tree</code>]

You can tweak this as desired. (For example, you probably want `cont` to be specified for the parent and not one of the children. I did it this way only because I initially thought of making it the child's `edge`.)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  declare toks={lpost}{left},
  my label/.style={
    if n=1{
      edge label={node [midway, left] {$#1$}}
    }{
      edge label={node [midway, right] {$#1$}}
    },
  },
  cont/.style={
    tikz+={
      \fill [fill=black, fill opacity=.5, blend mode=darken] (!u.children) -- ([xshift=25pt].center) -- ([xshift=-25pt].center) -- cycle;
    },
  },
  dec tree/.style={
    for tree={
      circle,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      l sep'+=25pt,
      s sep'+=25pt,
      calign=fixed edge angles,
    },
    where n children=1{draw, fill=white}{
      if n children=2{draw, fill=black}{},
    },
    where level=0{lpost=above}{
      if n'=1{lpost=right}{},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      where content={}{content=\ddots, inner ysep=0pt, child anchor=parent first, math content}{
        label/.process={ OOw2{content}{lpost}{##2:$##1$} },
        delay={content=},
      },
    }  
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  dec tree,
  [PM
    [l_i, my label=p, cont
      [PM, my label=A
        [l_i, my label=x, cont
          [x, my label=Y]
          [l_i, my label=N
            [l_i, my label=VNC
              [ne, my label=A]
              [, my label=\lnot A]
            ]
            [, my label=\lnot VNC]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Sq, my label=\lnot A]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Edit: `istgame` version 2.0

With the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) version 2, you can use a new macro `\istrootcntm` (instead of using `\istcntm` and `\istroot`) to draw a continuum of branches. Using `\istrootcntm` is simpler and more powerful than using `\istcntm` (discouraged to use the obsolete macro `\istcntm`). See also the use of input mode changer `\setistmathTF`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}    
\usepackage{istgame}    
\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[scale=2.5,font=\footnotesize]
\setistmathTF111 % all labels are in math mode
\xtdistance{8mm}{20mm}
\istrootcntm(0)[initial node]{PM}+8mm..12mm+
  \istb{p}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(a)(0-1)<150>{l_2}
  \istb{A}[l]
  \istb{\neg A}[r]{SQ}
  \endist
\istrootcntm(1)(a-1)[initial node]<180>{PM}+8mm..12mm+
  \istb{x}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(b)(1-1)<150>{l_2}
  \istb{Y}[l]{x}[bl]
  \istb{N}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(c)(b-2){l_i}
  \istb{VNC}[l]
  \istb{\neg VNC}[r]{\ddots}[br]
  \endist
\istroot(d)(c-1){l_i}
  \istb{A}[l]{ne}[bl]
  \istb{\neg A}[r]{\ddots}[br]
  \endist
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

#### Original answer

Here is another solution to use the package [istgame](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame), with which you can use `\istcntm` to draw a continuum of actions.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{istgame}
\begin{document}    
\begin{istgame}[scale=2.5,font=\footnotesize]
\xtdistance{8mm}{20mm}
\istcntm(ctm0)+8mm..12mm+
\istroot(0)(ctm0)[initial node]{$PM$}+\cntmlevdist..\cntmlevdist+
  \istb{p}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(a)(0-1)<150>{$l_2$}
  \istb{A}[l]
  \istb{\neg A}[r]{SQ}
  \endist
\istcntm(ctm1)(a-1)+8mm..12mm+
\istroot(1)(ctm1)[initial node]<180>{$PM$}+\cntmlevdist..\cntmlevdist+
  \istb{x}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(b)(1-1)<150>{$l_2$}
  \istb{Y}[l]{x}[bl]
  \istb{N}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(c)(b-2){$l_i$}
  \istb{VNC}[l]
  \istb{\neg VNC}[r]{\ddots}[br]
  \endist
\istroot(d)(c-1){$l_i$}
  \istb{A}[l]{ne}[bl]
  \istb{\neg A}[r]{\ddots}[br]
  \endist
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```